# Unable to execute command prompt command from python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

Unable to execute a ffmpeg command directly from python, however it works fine if used within the command prompt.

```
 os.system("cmd /c ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i sound.mp3 -c:v copy -filter_complex '[1:a] adelay=3000|2000 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]' -map 0:v -map '[out]' video2.mp4")



 '2000' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

I know it has something to do with the pipe |. I've looked at documentation to make subprocess work with pipes but without success.

Comment: Note that the details are quite different between Windows and Unixlike systems here; you should generally note your OS when the question isn't generic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `os.system()`, try [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (general advice), and separate your command into a *list* of strings (i.e., instead of a single space-separated string, pass it as `["cmd", "/c", "ffmpeg", "-i", "video.mp4", "-i", "sound.mp3", "-c:v", "copy", "-filter_complex", "'[1:a] adelay=3000|2000 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]'", "-map", "0:v", "-map", "'[out]'", "video2.mp4"]`). This may solve the problem, and at the very least should help with debugging.

Note that the pipe (`|`) in the [`adelay` argument](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#adelay) is *not* being used here as an I/O redirection operator (which is that character's most common meaning on the command line), so documentation about using pipes with `os.system` or `subprocess` calls probably won't be addressing the right thing.

It also may be worth thinking about whether your issue is an example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There is often a more Pythonic way to do things than a command-line call—have you looked into other possible solutions like the [ffmpy](https://ffmpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to see if it would work for your purposes?

Comment: subprocess.run() did indeed solve the problem. I was unaware that subprocess worked better but very glad it did.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes and other characters in the command sent can often lead to unexpected results, you can try this to wrap the command with like so:  os.system('''your_command''')

You can also try to to use escape characters:

```
cmd = '''cmd \/c ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i sound.mp3 -c\:v copy -filter_complex \'[1:a] adelay=3000\|2000 [delayed]; [0:a] [delayed] amix [out]\' -map 0:v -map \'[out]\' video2.mp4''' 
os.system(cmd)
```